# React Native Flatlist extraData not working redux data changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have array in redux. I am showing datas on Flatlist. However, When I edited array data , flatlist not re-render. How can i solve this problem? I checked my redux and is working fine

```
            this.props.notes[this.state.Index]={
                color: JSON.stringify(BgColor),
                date: this.state.fullDate.toString(),                    
                note: this.state.noteText,
                name: this.state.noteName,
                type: "note",
                noteID:this.props.notes[this.state.Index].noteID
            }
            this.props.editNotes(this.props.notes);
```

Flatlist code;

```
          <FlatList
            ref={(list) => this.myFlatList = list}           
            data={this.props.notes}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            renderItem={({item, index})=>(

            )}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}  
            extraData={this.props.notes}   
           />
```

mapStateToProps on same page with Flatlist

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { notes } = state
    return { notes }
};
```

Reducer

```
const notes = [];

const notesReducer = (state = notes, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'editNotes':
      return state = action.payload;
    default:
      return state
  }
};

export default notesReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's not updating the data correctly is because the mutation.

The problematic code is this part.

```
            this.props.notes[this.state.Index]={
                color: JSON.stringify(BgColor),
                date: this.state.fullDate.toString(),                    
                note: this.state.noteText,
                name: this.state.noteName,
                type: "note",
                noteID:this.props.notes[this.state.Index].noteID
            }
            this.props.editNotes(this.props.notes);
```

It should be in this way

```
const { notes, editNotes } = this.props; 
const newNotes = [...notes];
const { index } = this.state;
newNotes[index] = {
  //update data
} 
editNotes(newNotes);
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's not updating is because you're not returning a new array. The reference is same.

Return the updated state like `return [...state,action.payload]`

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the issue in many ways but the wrong part I see in your code is Reducer. As per the standard, your reducer should be a Pure Function and the state should not mutate.

```js
const notes = [];

const notesReducer = (state = notes, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'editNotes':
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.payload;
    },
    default:
      return state
  }
};

export default notesReducer;
```

This should resolve your issue.

Suggestion:
Try to create a nested hierarchy in redux like

```js
const initialState = {
 notes: [],
};

const notesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'editNotes':
      return {
        ...state,
        notes: [
          ...state.notes,
          ...action.payload.notes,
        ],
    },
    default:
      return state
  }
};

export default notesReducer;
```